# How to manage arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

I apologise in advance if I'm too bad at using the search engine and this has already been answered. Please point me in the right direction in that case.

I've recently begun to use the arguments variable in functions, and now I need to slice it. Everywhere I look people are doing things like:

```
function getArguments(args, start) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(args, start);
}
```

And according to MDN this is bad for performance:

> You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Is there a reason why I don't see anyone doing things like this:

```
function getArguments(args, start) {
    var i, p = 0;
    var len = args.length;
    var params = [];

    for (i = start; i < len; ++i) {
        params[p] = args[i];
        p += 1;
    }

    return params;
}
```

You get the arguments you want, and no slicing is done. So from my point of view, you don't loose anything on this, well maybe it uses a little extra memory and is slightly slower, but not to the point where it really makes a difference, right?

Just wanted to know if my logic here is flawed.

Comment: Passing `arguments` into another function will prevent optiomizations as well. So this is as bad as slicing.

Comment: This kind of microoptimization doesn't make much of a difference for most programs. I'd just slice and call it a day.

Comment: Agree with @elclanrs. Don't worry about it, until you are writing super high-loaded program, just use slice, it's good enough that you heard about browser optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [discuss](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2eppid/fastest_way_to_slice_arguments_in_javascript/)

and here is [introduction](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments)

e.g. [here](https://github.com/tj/node-thunkify/blob/master/index.js) uses the inline slice

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the discussion that @Eason posted, ([here](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2eppid/fastest_way_to_slice_arguments_in_javascript/)) that the debate is in the "microptimization" category, ie: most of us will never hit those performance bumps because our code isn't being run through the kind of iterations needed to even appear on the radar.

Here's a good quote that sums it up:

> Micro-optimizations like this are always going to be a trade-off
>   between the code's complexity/readability and its performance.
>
> In many cases, the complexity/readability is more important. In this case, the
>   very slowest method that was tested netted a runtime of 4.3
>   microseconds. If you're writing a webservice and you're slicing args
>   two times per request and then doing 100 ms worth of other work, an
>   extra 0.0086 ms will not be noticeable and it's not worth the time or
>   the code pollution to optimize.
>
> These optimizations are most helpful in really hot loops that you're hitting a gajillionty times. Use a
>   profiler to find your hot code, and optimize your hottest code first,
>   until the performance you've achieved is satisfactory.

I'm satisfied, and will use `Array.prototype.slice.call()` unless I detect a performance blip that points to that particular piece of code not hitting the V8 optimizer.